# Excel multiple if(or(isnumber function in one cell

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to display a value in a cell based on anothers criteria (IF).
So what I am trying to do is this (see picture as well).

IF the ECT Value is 32 ECT B or 32 ECT C THEN show "SP3-23M-SP3".
IF ECT Value is 44 ECT C or 44 ECT B then show "SP4-23M-SP4".
IF ECT Value is 51 ECT BC then show "SP3-23M-SP3-23M-SP3"

I've tried to use an array formula as well as an IF statement.

Array formula:

```
{=INDEX($B$A2:$B$A6,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$Z2:$A$Z6)),0)}
IF statement: =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("32 ECT C",AI4)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("32 ECT B",AI4))),"SP3-23M-SP3","False")
```

The array I am just getting an error. Not sure why. I pretty much toook that from a response on here. The If or statement is working - but for only the conditions I need to return as the one value. I need to do this for 2 other return values. Is that possible?

[image: picture of the spreadsheet I'm working with]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think its best to create a **Table of Reference** and then use a `LOOKUP` Function

Formula used in cell **AX2**

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($AZ$2:$AZ$6,$AI2),$BA$2:$BA$6)
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: This works! However, one more caveat. I wouldn't like to table referenced to be shown or accessible in the final spreadsheet. Any way to hide and lock without just hiding the rows?

Comment: @JosephHightower Sir, yes you can hide the columns but it won't be right to hardcode the `ECT` values within a function, since if in future if you want to change or increase the range then it will be a mess up hence its always best to create a table of reference and then use in a formula! Just place the `TOR` to far distant columns or in other worksheet and then hide the worksheet & use workbook protection.